# printf in gcc wrong result

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

Case 1:
`printf("%f",(7/2));` in gcc output is 0.000000.

Case 2: 
`float k= 7/2;`
`printf("%f",k);` in gcc output is 3.000000.

In the first case printf expects float but gets Integer so gives wrong result. But in second case it does type conversion.

Here are my questions-

1. Why does not gcc give type mismatch error/ warning in the first case?
2. In 2nd case it is doing type conversion by default but why not in 1st case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) gcc does not by default check types in format string with arguments - so it "interpretes" the data (ie. the integer) as float *at runtime*

2) gcc now interpretes the float as float *at runtime*.

Answer (score 8):

> In 2nd case it is doing type conversion by default but why not in 1st case?

In the first case, `7` and `2` both are of `int` type. Dividing `7` by `2` will give you an `int`. Printing it with `%f` will invoke **undefined behavior**. You will get anything. In this case there is no type conversion.

Try this

```
printf("%f", (7.0/2));
```

In the second case, `k` is of `float` type hence the result of `7/2` is converted to the type of `k` by default.

> Why does not gcc give type mismatch error/ warning in the first case?

Compiling the first statement with `-Wall` flag is giving the warning:

```
[Warning] format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
```

Answer (score 4):

GCC can give a warning, but you didn't enable it. Try compile with flag `-Wall`, you would see:

```
warning: double format, different type arg (arg 2)
```